# Matching an excel range to a different block of ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to take a row in the right and then match it to the row in the left, and the compare the two values.  I made this formula which can work on a single instance.

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(B6:F6,$I$5:$M$5))=COUNT($I$5:$M$5), IF($N$5=G6, "Match", "No-Match"), FALSE)`

[image]

The problem is when I have hundreds of rows on the right and left, the only solution I can think of is to make a massive matrix of tests.  Is it possible to condense this to a single cell, with built-in formulas or vba?

Comment: One way would be to concatenate the values on the left into a single cell with delimiters, and do the same on the right and then compare those. Would be more efficient but might still take time if you lots of data. VBA arrays would be faster.

Comment: You can use [WorksheetFunction.SumProduct Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-sumproduct-method-excel) and [CountIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-countif-method-excel) on VBA. And transform this function to a VBA code. And here are [three ways to compare in VBA](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/)

Comment: `Concat()`... it is always so simple... Thank you very much.

Comment: As stated a simple COUNTIFS() will do it: `=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,I5,C:C,J5,D:D,K5,E:E,L5,F:F,M5,G:G,N5),"Match", "No-Match")`

Comment: @ScottCraner - I always forget these new-fangled formulae.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use matrix formulas which are meant to process arrays rather than values.

If you wanted to see if ranges A1:A5 and B1:B5 had the same values you would use

```
=AND(A1:A5=B1:B5)
```

Don't forget to use **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** when you finish your formula, as it will specify that it is a matrix formula.

This example evaluates if A1=B1 and A2=B2 and outputs TRUE if all of the conditions are true.

To learn more about excel array formulas you can get started on [excel official help page about array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7).

Answer (score 0):

You can create two helper Columns like Column-G & Column-N. ( follow attached image)

Column-G Formula: =CONCATENATE(A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2) at row no. 2 and drag down to last.

Column-H Formula: =CONCATENATE(H2,I2,J2,K2,L2,M2) at row no. 2 and drag down to last.

Now at Column-O you can put "MATCH" formula to match the rows and if it's not match you will get #NA error

[image: Row Match Trick]